# Linux - importing “.” or “::” within the root PATH

Tags: path

I am looking into Miscellaneous Config and I am researching roots `PATH`. I am told that `.` and `::` should be removed from the path as it is a security threat. I have the following example output of the `PATH` command:

```
/usr/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bin/X11:/sbin:/usr/java7_64/jre/bin:/usr/java7_64/bin:/opt/IBM/xlC/13.1.3/bin
```

If this output was to contain `::` or `.` how would it look like within in the above path so I can have an idea on how it will be structured as I am not sure.

Really appreciate the help on this one.

Comment: ? It would contain `.` (appearing as `.:` at the beginning, `:.:` somewhere in the middle or `:.` at the end, obviously), or `::` (appearing as `:` at the beginning or at the end, `::` in the middle). The idea behind not having the current directory in the PATH (not only for root, but in general for any user) is that you may run an unwanted executable without realising, just because it happens to have the same name as a system command. The downside is that you need to prepend `./` if you *want* to run an executable from the current directory; this is neither hard nor complicated.

Comment: Also at: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51751741/4957508

Answer (score 1):

The `PATH` is just a colon-separated list of paths. If an entry is `.` or empty, it refers to the current directory. Also, leading and tailing empty entries count (they're created by leading or tailing colons).

So, if `PATH` is `/bin:/usr/bin`, it contains the two entries `/bin` and `/usr/bin`, so no reference to current directory.

On the other hand `/bin::/usr/bin:.:/usr/local/bin:` contains six entries: `/bin`, *empty*, `/usr/bin`, `.`, `/usr/local/bin` and *empty*. The `.` entries and the empty ones refer to the current path, these are the ones you don't want.

Parsing the `PATH` is likely to be easiest by splitting the string on the colons, and checking the resulting strings. How to do that exactly depends on your programming language.

Comment: Detecting a `.` entry is not trivial, as it could be `./` or `./././.` etc. I started writing something that compared each entry with `.` using the nonstandard `-ef` test, until I realised it would fail if the _current_ directory was a valid directory to have in `$PATH` (e.g. `$HOME/local/bin` or similar).

Comment: @Kusalananda, haha, that's right. I suppose `.` and empty are the most common ones, but `..` and variants could also be problematic. Maybe just demand a leading slash? (but not more than one, or at least not exactly two.)

Comment: That sounds like a good criteria, a valid absolute path.